Can FCLT pass through strong approximation?
Suppose we have a sequence $\{X_n\}$ and it satisfy a functional central limit theorem
$$ \frac{X_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}} \Rightarrow \frac{B(t)}{t},$$
where $B(t)$ is a standard brownian motion. On the other hand, there is another sequence $\{Y_n\}$ such that $\vert X_n - Y_n \vert \leq n^{-c}$, where $c>0$ is a constant.
Will the sequence $Y_n$ also have the FCLT like that of $X_n$?
I deeply appreciate any guidance on any related materials!

Yes and in fact, it would hold even if we only assume that $ \lvert X_n-Y_n\rvert\leqslant 1$. Indeed,
$$
\sup_{t\in [0,1]}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\lvert X_{\lfloor nt\rfloor}-Y_{\lfloor nt\rfloor}\rvert\leqslant\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}
$$
hence the convergence in $D[0,1]$ is preserved.

Many thanks for your reply! If we look at the original condition, $\vert X_{\lfloor n t \rfloor} - Y_{\lfloor n t \rfloor} \vert \leq {\lfloor n t \rfloor}^{-c}$. Then $\sup_{t\in[0,1]} \vert X_{\lfloor n t \rfloor} - Y_{\lfloor n t \rfloor} \vert / \sqrt{n} \leq {\lfloor n t \rfloor}^{-c}/\sqrt{n}$, where $t$ can take value from $(0,1)$. It seems that we can not bound the difference like above since we can let $t$ approaches $0$?

We use $\sup_{t\in [0,1]}a_{\lfoor nt\rfloor}\leq \max_{0\leq k\leq n}a_k\leqslant a_0+ \max_{1\leq k\leq n}a_k$ for non-negative $(a_k)$. Use the bound $a_k\leq k^{-\delta}$ for the second part. In other word, split the $\sup$ at $1/n$.

Got it, thanks!
